# Record is undefined Extjs4 to get the data out of the form

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have window with button enter and few fields i need to get the data out of the form and  there is method on button :

```
enter: function (button) {     
        var win = button.up('window'),
            form = win.down('form'),
            record = form.getRecord(),
            values = form.getValues();
        record.set(values);
        win.close();
        this.getUsersStore().sync();
```

Here record is undefined. What i do wrong?
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here the form:

```
Ext.define('ExtMVC.view.portlet.Login', {

    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.login',   
    layout: 'fit',
    title: 'LogIn',
    width: 300,
    height: 150,
    autoShow: true,
    store: 'LoginModels',

    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'form',                
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'Name',
                        fieldLabel: 'Name',
                        style: { 'margin': '10px' },
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'Password',
                        fieldLabel: 'Password',
                        style: { 'margin': '10px' },
                    }                    
                ]
            }
        ];

        this.buttons = [
            {
                text: 'Enter',
                action: 'enter',
                //handler: this.enter
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.close
            },
            {
                text: 'Sing in',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.close
            }
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);


    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try to replace with this code

```
values=form.getForm().getValues();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the ext doc as it clearly says:

getRecord( ) : Ext.data.Model : 
Returns the currently loaded Ext.data.Model instance if one was loaded via loadRecord.

And in case of your example I dont see any code that loads your form panel using loadRecord().

```
 enter: function (button) {     
    var win = button.up('window'),
        form = win.down('form'),            
        //record = form.getRecord(),   /*not required here*/
        record = this.getUsersStore().findRecord('id', 1) /*if you know id or some thing which field is know*/

        values = form.getValues();
    record.set(values);
    win.close();
    this.getUsersStore().sync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load form using form.loadRecord() before fetching it through form.getRecord(), otherwise form.getRecord() returns undefined.

Comment: What do you mean? what i need write?